# Excel to Word VBA - Export data with a logo every x rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, formatting

I'm trying to create a set of *plates* (group of 5 rows with some data took from the mainsheet) and create a Word file that put 2 plate per page. Before every plate i wanna insert a logo (i'm trying to add the logo in the for cycle but i'm lost right now), with a custom style (the same as the result page)
I have part of the code i came up with until now, and i show you the result i'm trying to obtain:
(First pic the final result, the second the result i'm obtaining right now)

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintLabels_Word()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsPDF As Worksheet, xWs As Worksheet, WdObj As Object
Dim iLastRow As Long, ar(1 To 7, 1 To 1), rng As Range
Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Integer, k As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim area As Range
Dim saveLocation As String
Dim strFileName As String, myRow As Long

  
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Summary")
Set wsPDF = wb.Sheets("Foglio1")
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
wsPDF.Cells.Clear
xWs.ResetAllPageBreaks


' fixed
ar(1, 1) = ws.Cells(1, 10)
ar(2, 1) = "CLIENT: " & ws.Cells(1, 7)
ar(3, 1) = "ORDER" & " " & ws.Cells(2, 7)
ar(5, 1) = "JOB" & " " & ws.Cells(1, 2) & " " & ws.Cells(1, 3)
ar(6, 1) = "CASE NUMBER: 1/1"

iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
r = 1 ' start row
c = 1 ' column A
For i = 6 To iLastRow
    ar(4, 1) = "INSIDE CASE (TAG):  " & ws.Cells(i, "H")
    
   
    ' fill plate
    Set rng = wsPDF.Cells(r, c).Resize(7, 1)
    rng.Value2 = ar
   
    ' merge cells
    For k = 1 To 7
        With rng.Cells(k, 1).Resize(1, 4)
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next
    
    r = r + 8
            
Next

MsgBox "Done"
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.Orientation = xlPortrait
.Zoom = 200
.FitToPagesTall = False
.FitToPagesWide = False

End With

Dim tblRange As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

iLastRow = wsPDF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set tblRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A1:D" & iLastRow)

On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

'WordApp.Visible = True
'WordApp.Activate

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

tblRange.Copy
WordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
LinkedToExcel:=False, _
WordFormatting:=False, _
RTF:=False


With WordApp
.ChangeFileOpenDirectory ThisWorkbook.Path
.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="Targhetta Adesiva" & " " & ws.Range("B3").Value & "_" & 
ws.Range("G1").Value & ".doc"
.ActiveDocument.Close
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Final Result]
[image: Result right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to re-invent the wheel. Word already has all the functionality you need. It is called a mail merge (or Mailing) and it can use data from Excel.

To get multiple plates on one page, start with a Label merge setup and customise the layout table to suit your needs.

To do a mail merge with images, store all the images into one folder, put a unique image ID and each image path into the Excel source as two separate data columns. Then plug that information into the image merge field.

For more details see https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2675-using-mailmerge-to-insert-images

All that can be done without writing a single line of VBA.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a newbie so i didn't know that! I will absolutely look into it, thanks again ;)

Comment: For more on mailmerge graphics - plus a host of other things you probably haven't thought about - see the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html